# Error Running coomand swirl() for Swirl2.4.0 on Rstudio 3.3.3 on MAC 10.9.5

Tags: r, macos, swirl

```
> swirl()
Error in match.arg(type, c("success", "failure", "error", "skip", "warning")) : 
  'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

| Leaving swirl now. Type swirl() to resume.

> devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
 os       OS X Mavericks 10.9.5       
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Asia/Kolkata                
 date     2020-05-26                  

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version  date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1    2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 backports     1.1.7    2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 bitops        1.0-6    2013-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.0)
 callr         3.4.3    2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 cli           2.0.2    2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 crayon        1.3.4    2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 curl          4.3      2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 desc          1.2.0    2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 devtools      2.3.0    2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 digest        0.6.25   2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 ellipsis      0.3.1    2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 fansi         0.4.1    2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 fs            1.4.1    2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 glue          1.4.1    2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 httr          1.4.1    2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 magrittr      1.5      2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.0)
 memoise       1.1.0    2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 pkgbuild      1.0.8    2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 pkgload       1.0.2    2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 prettyunits   1.1.1    2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 processx      3.4.2    2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 ps            1.3.3    2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 R6            2.4.1    2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 RCurl         1.95-4.9 2017-12-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 remotes       2.1.1    2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 rlang         0.4.6    2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 rprojroot     1.3-2    2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.2)
 rstudioapi    0.11     2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1    2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 stringi       1.4.6    2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 stringr       1.4.0    2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 swirl       * 2.4.0    2016-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 testthat      2.3.2    2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 usethis       1.6.1    2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 withr         2.2.0    2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
 yaml          2.2.1    2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.3.3)
```

I Do not know what the error I have referred to previous queries here and on Github. I have updated remotes and `testthat` (recommended solutions) but none of the following has worked.

Comment: Maybe update R? v3.3.3 is quite old now.

Comment: Hey Phil, Mac OS 10.9.5 supports latest till 3.3.3 but thanks

Answer (score 0):

First remove testthat,crayon,Rcurl and swirl
the versions you require of each should be testthat version .11 , Rcurl 1.95-4.7 and swirl 2.4.0
make sure you have these and it will work for sure